# what does trigger's IF syntax mean in following program?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql5

```
DELIMITER $$  
create trigger mytable_check before insert on test.mytable for each row  
begin  
 if new.id_category in ('list','of','special','categories')  
    and exists  
      (select * from mytable  
       where id_category=new.id_category  
         and keywords=new.keywords) then  
    call fail(concat('id_category,keywords must be unique when id_category is: ',new.id_category));  
 end if;  
end $$  
DELIMITER ;
```

I am having slight problem in understanding this trigger statement. Can u please explain me this statement?What does

**`if new.id_category in ('list','of','special','categories')`**

statement mean??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new.id_category = 'list'
or
new.id_category = 'of'
or
new.id_category = 'special'
or
new.id_category = 'categories'
```

Comment: is there any way to allow range of values to match ? like
new.id_category=1
or
new.id_category=2
or
new.id_category=3
and so on???